# Add HTMLelement to RootPanel in GWT

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I have a `<div>` in my HTML page. What I need to do is, add `<ul>` element inside it from my Entry point class. I have tried from onModuleLoad function using below code,

```
UListElement ul=Document.get().createULElement();
    ImageElement img=Document.get().createImageElement();
    img.setSrc("\\images\\personas");
    LIElement li=Document.get().createLIElement();
    li.appendChild(img);
    ul.appendChild(li);
    Document.get().getElementById("divPhotos").appendChild(ul);
```

but my `<div>` is empty/has no childs when i run it. what am I missing here?

Comment: no, your code runs fine for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have forgot to add nocache.js in html page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="test/test.nocache.js"></script>
```

Its working now...

Answer (score 1):

Your code is okay assuming you have correctly assigned the "divPhotos" id to a div in your HTML DOM. I suspect that you are viewing the page source and expecting to see the newly appended DOM elements. What you want to view is the pages live DOM. How you inspect the DOM in depends on the web browser you are using. if your using Google Chrome, press F12 to access the debugging tools which will allow you to transverse the live DOM. For Firefox, you need to install Firebug. Other browsers provide their own debugging mechanisms.